# Pull and subscribe to firebase data in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, promise

I have what should be a very simple task. I want to pull a document from a `firestore` database collection using Angular. Since it may take a few seconds for this action to be completed, I run into a problem where I need to either wait for that data or subscribe to it.

I am baffled that there isn't a clear, concise, and simple explanation of this in some sort of documentation somewhere. I have spent several hours now and found multiple explanations - none of which work.

The following will work to pull the data. However, the issue is that it is already written before the data returns.

Component call to service

```
this.userInfo = this.UserService.getUserInfo( this.userData.uid )
```

Service Call

```
getUserInfo( userId ) {
    var docRef = this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId);
    docRef.ref.get().then(function(doc){ return doc.data()});
}
```

You won't find the .ref explained anywhere that I have seen. As I said, this data is passed to a child component and the delay means that the data is not passing through to the component. I tried subscribing to it, but could not get it to work.

I just want an explanation as to how it is supposed to be done, not a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood and by looking at the code, it returns a `Promise`, so you need to use it asynchronous way

**Service.ts**

```
getUserInfo( userId ) {
    var docRef = this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId);
    return docRef.ref.get()
}
```

**component.ts**

```
this.UserService.getUserInfo( this.userData.uid ).then(response=> {
   this.userInfo = response.data(); 
})
```

Try this and let me know

Comment: @JoshuaFoxworth: Feel  free to upvote as well . About to touch 10k :D